# specific integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics

Hi so I'm wondering about specific integer partitions. So for example I want to look at the partitions of the number 30 and I want there to be 10 numbers in my set but each of them must be 3,4,or 6. So in this case there's only one such partition, namely 10 number 3's.
What if I wanted to do this with different constraints? I've read up a little on it but haven't found anything for such specifics. Is there a quick theoretical way, or is a computer programme my best bet?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute, the best way is a computer(some dp should work).
Although if you want a math way, then you are lookin for this number
$$[x^{30}y^{10}]\frac{1}{(1-x^3y)(1-x^4y)(1-x^6y)}.$$
Just use the geometric series and $x$ keeps track of the summand and $y$ the numbers of summands.